# Gaussian integral with matrix exponents

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral, matrix-exponential

In general, it is known that for any constants $a$, $b$, $c$ with $a>0$, the gaussian integral which is quadratic in $x$ is given as
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^{2}+bx+c}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{\frac{b^{2}}{4a}+c}
$$
I would like to extend this to matrices, in general, how do I show that this equation also hold for matrices? Alternately, I'm asking what is the following gaussian integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\textbf{A}x^{2}+\textbf{B}x+\textbf{C}}dx
$$
where $\textbf{A}$, $\textbf{B}$, and $\textbf{C}$ are $N\times N$ matrices?

Comment: To we get to assume anything about the matrices, such as diagonalizability, symmetry, definiteness? Seems like at least $A$ wants to be positive definite here.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes! $\textbf{A}$, $\textbf{B}$, $\textbf{C}$ are all positive definite and diagonalizable. My approach was to use $N=2$ and define arbitrary two by two matrices for $\textbf{A}$, $\textbf{B}$, $\textbf{C}$ and try Taylors expanding the matrix exponential, hoping to find a convergence trend. But it became too complicated and intractable.

Comment: I believe I can prove that if $\mathbf{A}$ has only positive eigenvalues that $\mathbf{G} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-\mathbf{A}x^2)dx$ satisfies $\mathbf{G}^2\mathbf{A} = \pi \mathbf{I}$ even if $\mathbf{A}$ isn't diagonalizable. That's about as far as I got with this. $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ possibly not commuting makes things very complicated.